# Set GridView BoundField in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to set the datasource as my bound field item, but i failed to do so, my output is not as my expected

**output**

boundfield userName movieComment

**expected output**

boundfield

---

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand cmdReadComment = new SqlCommand("SELECT  [userName],[movieComment] FROM [movieCommentTable] WHERE [movieTitle]='" + lblHeadTitle.Text + "'", conn);

SqlDataReader dtrReadComment;
conn.Open();

dtrReadComment = cmdReadComment.ExecuteReader();

GridView2.DataSource = dtrReadComment;

GridView2.RowStyle.Height = 200;


BoundField userNameBF = new BoundField();
userNameBF.DataField = "userName";
userNameBF.ItemStyle.Width = 180;
GridView2.Columns.Add(userNameBF);        

GridView2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `GridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;`. [Read more on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx).

This way you tell `GridView` not to generate columns on its own.

Another solution can be, change your query to

```
SELECT  [userName] FROM [movieCommentTable] WHERE...
```

And comment out your custom code for `BoundField`.

Hope this works for you

Comment: i can only accept ur answer at next 8 minutes, but by the way i am going out ,so i will only accept ur answer after i back=)

Comment: No problemo... Glad it worked for you. Can you upvote? Never asked any question here, so don't know about the restriction applied.